# Eager loading relationships to sort by is not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to use Eager Loading to dynamically order by relationships in Laravel.

```
dd(SomeModel::with(['someRelation' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderByDesc('column');
})->toSql());
```

I'm using `dd()` and `toSql()` to try to debug what is happening and this is what I see:

> "select * from "some_table" where "some_table"."deleted_at" is null"

No matter if I `orderBy('column', 'ASC')` or `orderBy('column', 'DESC')` without the `dd` or `toSql`, I get the same output as if it is ignoring the entire eager load.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? My relation in this case looks like this:

```
class SomeModel
{
    protected $table = 'some_table'; # for visual aid
    
    public function someRelation(): BelongsTo
    {
        $this->belongsTo(SomeOtherModel::class)->select('id', 'column');
    }
}
```

FYI, some more debug later. I attempted to try see if the function ever executes, to which it does:

```
SomeModel::with(['someRelation' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderByDesc('column');
    dd($query->toSql());
});
```

The `dd` block executes telling me the function executed and gives me:

> "select "id", "name" from "some_other_table" where "some_other_table"."id" in (?, ?) and "some_other_table"."deleted_at" is null order by "name" desc"

Any help appreciated.

Update to check for subqueries SQL:

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();

SomeModel::with(['someRelation' => function ($test) {
    $test->orderBy('name', 'DESC');
}])->get();

dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
```

This returns me an empty array:

> []

Comment: `->with()` doesn't affect the `SomeModel` results returned, but it will sort the `SomeRelation` sub-collection. If you want to sort by a column in a different table, you'll need to use `->join()` of some kind.

Comment: But the part I don't get is I use this exact method elsewhere and it works perfectly fine, only now when I'm trying to do it elsewhere is it causing me issues on another model. I got it [from here](https://reinink.ca/articles/ordering-database-queries-by-relationship-columns-in-laravel) and it does seem to work on all my other models, only now on this model for some peculiar reason is it not working. @TimLewis

Comment: You might need to modify your question to show that scenario, including list with and without sorting triggered by inclusion of a `->with()` clause... What you're describing goes against my experience with Laravel and relationships...

Comment: From that link you posted, you can see it's doing `->join()` in a couple spots, and there isn't a single usage of `->with()` in that entire article, probably for the reason I stated above...

Comment: I have no idea how its working elsewhere then, I actually totally miss-read the `load` for `with` which is interesting. I do it dynamically in a `helpers.php` file. The front-end sends a `sortBy` which contains something like `someModel.user` to which I hash-map (array) back to a relation and column which then builds a an array `with()` expects. This works everywhere I try it elsewhere :S @TimLewis

Comment: Yeah, `->load()` is a similar method, i.e. accomplishes the same thing as `->with()`, but that happens after a Model or Collection has already been queried and is available, as opposed to `->with()` which happens while a Model or Collection is being queried from the DB. That `helpers.php` approach sounds pretty interesting, but I'm not sure how you're accomplishing that sort via a `->with()` clause to be honest... Maybe include that code in your question, unless it's not something you'd like to share (private code, etc)

Comment: Oh also, `->toSql()` generally doesn't show subqueries, such as via `->with()`. You can use `DB::enableQueryLog()` before, perform the query with `->get()`, then run `dd(DB::getQueryLog());` to show the query and subqueries executed.

Comment: Unfortunately it is, hence why I tried to provide a minimalistic, reproducible example. If you don't mind chatting over on Discord or something I'd be happy to share? If you really wouldn't mind that? Thanks for that information though, I'll do that now and see what the query log shows! @TimLewis

Comment: Totally understandable, and I appreciate the effort and honesty regardless. I unfortunately won't be available for a private chat or anything, but see if you can do some more debugging with that new information and see what kinda of queries are being executed; maybe it can shed some light on that. Cheers, and best of luck!

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis I appreciate the time and comments either way! I updated my question with some weird output. Even if I don't execute with `->get()` it still returns an empty array :S

Comment: That is super bizarre... `DB::enableQueryLog()` and `DB::getQueryLog()` both work fine for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULOCz.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0p94.png

Comment: I honestly don't understand why its not working, its almost as if something just isn't firing in Laravel as it should be and I'm not getting any debug back :S @TimLewis I'm going to try and write a dynamic way of joining like you suggested

Comment: Sounds good; keep at it, I have faith you'll find the answer eventually. Also, unless you're calling [`flushQueryLog()`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/DB.html#method_flushQueryLog), there's not much reason it would be empty... Although it looks like those methods weren't introduced until version `6.x`; are you on a Laravel version earlier than that? I would suspect you'd get an error trying to call those though... So that's a stretch.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I ended up just switching my entire application to use dynamic joins which has resolved the issue. Thanks @TimLewis - I'm still totally unsure what is bugging in my application, I'm on Laravel `8.x` but I've moved away from using `with`

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the full article as @TimLewis alluded to, I went with the `join` solution.

```
SomeModel::query()->select('some_table.id', 'some_table.name') # Only bring back what we need without the join
    ->join('some_other_table', 'some_other_table.id', '=', 'some_table.some_other_table_id')
    ->orderByDesc('column');
```

Alternatively, you can always `leftJoin` if you don't expect data all the time, just make some null exception handling.

I actually created an abstract class which has a global scope to do this dynamically in any Model based on a hash-map approach.